# Manage large GridView with images (OutOfMemoryException)

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I have a GridView that have to load a lot of items (around 300) with images, these images are downloaded from Internet using UniversalImageLoader. The problem that I have is about memory (OutOfMemoryException).

That's the code of my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    View v = convertView;

    ViewHolder vh = null;
    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_gridview, null);

        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagenCategoria);

        v.setTag(vh);  

        TextView nombreElemento = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nombreElemento);
        nombreElemento.setText(elementos.get(position).getTitulo());

        TextView infoElemento = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.infoElemento);
        infoElemento.setText(elementos.get(position).getCalidad()+"  "+elementos.get(position).getLenguaje()+"  "+elementos.get(position).getAnho());



    }else {
        vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }

    ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(vh.imageView, false);
    String coverUrl = elementos.get(position).getUrlCover();
    if(coverUrl!=null && !coverUrl.equals(""))imageLoader.displayImage(coverUrl, imageAware);


    return v;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

And that's the configuration of my ImageLoader object:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .bitmapConfig(Config.RGB_565)                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration configs = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context.getApplicationContext())
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .discCacheSize(104857600)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .imageDownloader(new HttpClientImageDownloader(c, new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params))).threadPoolSize(10).build();

    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(configs);
```

Does anyone know the solution? Best.

Comment: you can either cache on Disc or clear cache onLowMemory() by calling @Override
 public void onLowMemory() {
  ImageLoader.getInstance().clearMemoryCache();
  super.onLowMemory();
 }

Answer (score 0):

you can clear cache in onLowMemory() by calling

```
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().clearMemoryCache();
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this method, but I think it doesn't work because that method is executed when the whole system runs low on memory, not my app. Is there any way to hide the bitmap of an item when that item isn't showed? Because when I do scroll all bitmaps are visibles, they aren't charged when I do scroll.

Comment: have you created viewholder for getView in adapter class?

Comment: you can remove .cacheInMemory(true)